# How is mkdir subject to a TOCTOU attack?

Tags: vulnerability, file-access

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59046435/8446), resulted in this comment:

> This could be subject to a TOCTOU<sup>1</sup> attack and needs to be developed to be correct.

The answer is in Rust, but here's some equivalent bash:

```
p=/home/roger/foo/bar/baz.txt
d=$(dirname $p)
mkdir -p $d
# ...and then (implied):
echo "Hello World" > $p
```

Where is the TOCTOU vulnerability in this? How can it be improved?

---

<sup>1</sup> Time Of Check - Time Of Use

Comment: There is no [C]heck in your code at all and thus there is no [T]ime [O]f [C]heck. Which means that the time of the non-existent check cannot conflict with the time of use. Of course this does not mean that the code is safe if you create the directory in a place a potential attacker can write into since you don't make sure that the directory is owned and writable only by you.